# IOS uiviewcontroller: will the viewcontroller be free if rootviewcontroller is set to a new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a two UIViewControllers: loginViewController and MainViewController.

My app logic is like this:

1. In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I check if the user is already logged in.
   If yes, I go to MainViewController.
   If no, I go to loginViewController to let him login and then go to MainViewController.
2. When user is in MainViewController, he can log out. When he logs out, he will go to LoginViewController.

All the viewControllers are programmatically created. So when user is in MainViewController, when he clicks logout button, I created a new loginViewController and set rootViewController to it.

My question is:
If the user go to MainViewController through loginViewController, MainViewController.presentingViewController is loginViewController and loginViewController.presentedViewController is MainViewController, will they be freed at some point or they will always stay in memory when I set rootViewController to newly created loginViewController?

Since the logout button may not necessarily be in MainViewController, how can I go to loginViewController from logout button's viewController? If I use presentViewController, will there be too many duplicated viewController created? If I set rootViewController to loginViewController, how will other viewControllers be freed if they have strong reference to each other through presentingViewController and presentedViewController?

I'm little confused about the lifecycle of viewControllers...

Sorry about the long description...

Thanks,
-Lee

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question "will they be freed at some point or they will always stay in memory when I set rootViewController to newly created loginViewController"

They will be freed (unless they are retained by something not mentioned in your post). If `loginViewContorller` is the window's rootViewController and has `mainViewController` presented on it, then if you create a new `loginViewContorller` and replace the window's rootViewController with it, then the old `loginViewContorller` and `mainViewController` will be freed.

---

To answer your second question.
Don't worry. If at any point in time you replace the window's rootViewController with a new view controller, then UI will instantly switch to the newly created view controller and all other view controllers will be freed.

Think of it as a tree. Window's rootViewController is the trunk. All other view controllers are branching from it. So if you replace rootViewController with a new view controller, the whole hierarchy is freed **again assuming no other object keeps a strong reference to any of the view controllers**

Comment: Thanks for answering. But they are pointed to each other by presentedViewController and presentingViewControler. These two properties are not weak. Then why will they be freed?

Comment: @user1165560 you are in fact correct! It appears that presented view controller has a strong cross reference with the presenting view controller, which surprised me. I've looked into this, and presented view controllers behavior is unintuitive and in my opinion flawed. You might want to check these three examples I've prepared https://gist.github.com/bartekchlebek/4b2568e22f372bd8cd2f

Comment: Thanks for you example. Does it mean I should use push instead of present after login since mainView is not going to be dismissed by loginView. Perhaps using presenting is wrong...

Comment: @user1165560 it's hard to say. I avoid modals as much as possible because it is not the first time they produce problems for me. It's sooo easier to manage viewControllers stack in UINavigationController. On the other hand, presentViewController: API is there for a reason, and in some situations we are pretty much forced to use it. But if I'm to advice anything, go with `UINavigationController` if you can.

Comment: Got it. I should use push for in this case. Now I understand when to use Modals a little more :-)